# Ordering a Data Frame in R by Columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am observing some strange behaviours when ordering a data frame by column names. Basically when the data frame has only one column, on ordering, it looses the column name, but this doesn't happen when it has multiple columns. This is a sample code:

```
df <- data.frame(c("1", "2", "3"), c("4", "5", "6"), c("7", "8", "9"))
colnames(df) <- c("A", "C", "B")
df <- data.frame(df[,order(colnames(df))])
print(colnames(df))


df <- data.frame(c("1", "2", "3"))
colnames(df) <- c("A")
df <- data.frame(df[,order(colnames(df))])
print(colnames(df))
```

In the first part of the code, data frame `df`, preserves its columns but in the second part it loses the column name.

Obviously one can check for the number of columns and bring their name back if there is only one column, but it sounds like a bad practice.

Does anyone know any nicer way to handle the issue?

Comment: good old `drop` problem. use: `data.frame(df[,order(colnames(df)),drop=F])`

Comment: A better method in this instance is to use the list syntax: `df[order(colnames(df))]` will preserve the list structure ( and the associated names), while `df[order(colnames(df)),]` will drop the list structure in the instance of a single column data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tibble` instead of `data.frame`:

```
library(tibble)
df <- tibble(c("1", "2", "3"), c("4", "5", "6"), c("7", "8", "9"))
colnames(df) <- c("A", "C", "B")
df <- df[,order(colnames(df))]
print(colnames(df))


df <- tibble(c("1", "2", "3"))
colnames(df) <- c("A")
df <- df[,order(colnames(df))]
print(colnames(df))
```

Comment: why should anyone install a package and change the data structure for such an easy task?

Comment: True that. But if you always use tibbles as I do, you don't have this problem. But maybe others instead ;-)

Comment: In this case you don't need `data.frame()` anymore, `df <- df[, order(colnames(df))]` should work fine

Comment: @ANG absolutely right, I was a little sloppy. Edited accordingly. But anyway, @Andre Elrico's solution is better because you don't need another package if you don't use tibbles at all. Was not aware of that `drop=FALSE`, thus learned something today, too.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use select to order the columns

```
df %>% select_(.dots = sort( colnames(df) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Coutesy of Andre Elrico in the first comment, the most straight forward solution seems to be using the drop:

```
data.frame(df[,order(colnames(df)),drop=F])
```